# MySQL: Matching objects by their common tags

Tags: mysql, sql, match, matching

I have the following tables structure:

```
pizza_tags
  id
  pizza_id
  tag_id

order_tags
  id 
  order_id
  tag_id

--

tags
  id
  tag (text)
```

***Each pizza, as well as an order, can have multiple tags.***

The question is how to find the best pizza for a given order (order_id). The more "matching" tags Pizza and Order have, the better pizza we can find for any given order.

I tried a handful of different SQL queries with intersections and joins, but didn't find a more or less quick query which will solve the described problem.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is a join between the two tag tables, on the `tag_id`.  The rest is just aggregation, filtering, and counting.

```
select ot.order_id, count(*) as NumMatching
from order_tags ot join
     pizza_tags pt
     on ot.tag_id = pt.tag_id
where pt.pizza_id = @PIZZA_ID
group by ot.order_id
order by NumMatching desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you should be able to accomplish this using a subquery. Something like this:

```
SELECT o.id, o.order_id, o.tag_id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pizza_tags AS p WHERE p.tag_id = o.tag_id) AS p_tags
FROM order_tags AS o
GROUP BY o.order_id, o.tag_id
ORDER BY p_tags DESC;
```

Basically, you are getting any `pizza_tags` that match your `order_tags.tag_id` and sorting them with the most relevant first.

I have put together a minimal Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/587339/2).